# General matrix element of electromagnetic current between states of different masses?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, non-perturbative

Weinberg (Chapter 10, problem 3) in Quantum Theory of Fields Volume 1 asks for the matrix element:

$$\langle {\mathbf{p}_2\sigma_2}|{J^{\mu}(x)}|{\mathbf{p}_1\sigma}\rangle $$

of the electromagnetic current between two spin-$1/2$ one-particle states, of different masses $m_1$ and $m_2$ and equal parity?

How are particles of two masses even connected by the electromagnetic vertex, i.e. how does $J^\mu$ connect states on different hyperboloids, $p^2 = -m^2$?

Comment: What Weinberg textbook? He has a bunch of textbooks. This is not Chapter 10 Problem 3 from his Lecture notes in QM textbook (2nd edition).

Comment: Edited the question, thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 0):

The particle fields in the standard model are distinguish into different families, but that does not mean these particles are mass eigenstates. The mass terms are represented by matrices. As a result, there is a probability for a particle in one family to be converted into a particle of another family via the mass term.

Comment: Thanks for your response, I understand that in general, in SM, we can have vertices that can connect different masses. My question, and Weinberg's question is how does the electromagnetic vertex connect states of two masses. Please put the proof in the answer if you have an idea.

Comment: Also, in irreps of Poincare group $P^2$ (with eigenvalue $-m^2$ for a state) is a Casimir operator I believe, i.e. Poincare transformations will not change mass. But sure, some vertex could have matrix element between states of different mass. I don't know how the electromagnetic vertex would though.

Comment: @physicsbootcamp Are you thinking about the lowest order vertex? Yeah that interaction doesn't connect different mass particles. But Chapter 10 is about non-perturbative methods. So, presumably at higher orders if you have, say, two types of fermions that both interact with the same type of force carrier, you can have higher order contributions that connect different mass particles.

Comment: Hey thanks, I don't think it's that, I think this is something fundamental I am missing. Something in relativistic QM of these particles and how the fields are build in chapter 5, but if you see how you could write a general matrix elements using your approach, please let me know.